# <td> width not working in my table

Tags: html, css

I have this sample:

[link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KzQxBj)

**CODE HTML:**

```
<table class="table prospects-table">
            <thead>
            <tr>

                <th width="200">Name</th>
                <th width="200">Email</th>
                <th width="200">Phone</th>
                <th width="200">Message</th>
                <th width="200">Actions</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
                   <tbody>
                     <tr>
                       <td width="200">test sdada</td>
                       <td width="200">asdsada@yahoo.com</td>
                       <td width="200">(321) 312-3123</td>
                       <td width="200"> sadasda</td>
                       <td width="200">



                         <div class="in-line">
                            <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
                            <a href="http://192.168.0.105/user/editenewleed/22"><span>Edit</span></a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="in-line">
                            <i class="fa fa-users "></i>
                         <a href="http://192.168.0.105/user/addpatientfromnewlead/22"><span>Transfer</span></a>
                        </div>


                        <div class="in-line">
                            <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                            <a href="http://192.168.0.105/user/deletenewleed/22"><span>Delete</span></a>
                        </div>




                    </td></tr>
                                   <tr>
                       <td width="200">Diaconescu Cristian</td>
                       <td width="200">asdsadsa@busteco.rh</td>
                       <td width="200">(312) 312-3123</td>
                       <td width="200">asdasadsdasasasasdkhsdjkashsdkjahdhjsgdhjgvhhs,ajfkghjkdjhdsgjhasdghjgsadhjgshjkhvjgjkgfkjhdkjjhgfhjkdhkjsgdfv</td>
                       <td width="200">



                         <div class="in-line">
                            <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
                            <a href="http://192.168.0.105/user/editenewleed/24"><span>Edit</span></a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="in-line">
                            <i class="fa fa-users "></i>
                         <a href="http://192.168.0.105/user/addpatientfromnewlead/24"><span>Transfer</span></a>
                        </div>


                        <div class="in-line">
                            <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                            <a href="http://192.168.0.105/user/deletenewleed/24"><span>Delete</span></a>
                        </div>  
                    </td></tr>                
         </tbody>
</table>
```

I want each column of my table to have a width of 200px.

I added this code to each td but does not work ...

```
<td width="200">test sdada</td>
```

Probably something simple but I realize why this code does not work.

Can you tell me please what is the problem and how to solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Add `table-layout: fixed;` to your table

```
table{
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Updated **[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YqeJXv)**

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just add a style tag to your code?

In the head just insert this:

```
<style>
td,th {width:200px}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<td style="width: 200px;">test sdada</td>
```

learn proper css take a loot at element level css [here](http://www.w3schools.com/)

Answer (score 0):

you can add css :

```
style="width:200px";
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/4e32uyhe/1/)

Comment: but why not go long text below ... Message column is very long still

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
<td width="70%">JXXXXXX</td>
```

hope this one help you

Answer (score 0):

Width attribute is deprecated one. So it is better to use css width property instead.

> Usage Note: Do not use this attribute, as it has been deprecated and
>   the rules should be defined and styled using CSS. Use the CSS property
>   width instead. - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table)

```
td, th {
  width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

width of td doesn't  work at HTML5, 
use CSS styles instead , for example in simplest way

```
<style type="text/css">
  .tdw{
  width:200px;
  }
</style>
 <td class="tdw">Diaconescu Cristian</td>
```